# Create buffer zone within a Numpy array

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I have a binary image as follows:

```
data = np.array([[0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])
```

For pixels having 1s values, I want to make buffer zone of two pixels with value 1s surrounded in every four directions. The expected result would be:

```
result=np.array([[1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1]])
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Is it an array of only ones and zeros, or are there other values?

Comment: yes, its just 1s and 0s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have ones and zeros on the input and output array, you can do it with a 2D convolution, which is simple and works.

```
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

data = np.array([[0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])

# the kernel doesn't need to be ones, it just needs to be positive and
# non-zero.
kernel = np.ones((5, 5))

result = np.int64(convolve2d(data, kernel, mode='same') > 0)
```

Which gives you the output you want. You need to define what you want to happen at the edges - in this version, the output array is the same size as the input array.

It might be possible you can do something faster if you have a sparse array.

If you have other values than one and zero in your array, more thought would be needed.

Comment: Why would you need "a positive and non-zero kernel"? I can't see any reason why, and the documentation does not mention this either (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html).

Comment: You don't for the `convolve2d`, but you do for the method to work (specifically, the `> 0`).

Comment: @HenryGomersall Thanks for your answer. Could you explain me why you have used kernel of (5,5).

Comment: That creates a 5x5 array of ones. Are you familiar with convolution? It's probably a bit involved to explain in a comment, but in essence, the 5x5 shape is what you desire at the output for a single `1` in the input.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that the 2D kernel is separable, so you can do this with a pair of 1D kernels along each dimension, which would be faster if that's an issue.

Comment: If speed is an issue, switching to `dtype=int8` in both `data` and `kernel` would also probably speed things up, compared to using floats (as is done currently).

Comment: @EOL one would think so, but I can't detect much of a difference using the scipy convolve2d function. That's not to say an alternative version wouldn't be better with a different type.

Comment: @HenryGomersall Same here. Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it using [morphological `dilation`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/applications/plot_morphology.html) operator (which dilates the `ones` in this case).

```
from skimage.morphology import square, dilation
data = np.array([[0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])
result = dilation(data, square(5))
```

Note that `square(5)` is equivalent to `np.ones((5,5))` in this case. Dilation operator works by dilating `True` or `1` pixels with the element passed as a second parameter (in this case, a `5x5` square centered at each pixel).