# NumPy Convolve In One Direction Only

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I have a binary image as follows:

```
data = np.array([[1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1]])
```

For pixels having 0s values, I want to extend it 2 pixels towards south direction only.
The expected result would be:

```
result = np.array([[1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                  [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                  [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1],
                  [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1],
                  [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1],
                  [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1],
                  [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1]])
```

How can I do it?

I saw related question and answer below:

[Create buffer zone within a Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29027249/create-buffer-zone-within-a-numpy-array)

```
result = np.int64(convolve2d(data, np.ones((5, 5)), mode='same') > 0)
```

However, I want to convolve in one direction only

Answer (score 4):

use `scipy.ndimage.binary_erosion()`:

```
from scipy import ndimage

data = np.array([[1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1]])

kernel = [[1], [1], [1], [0], [0]]
ndimage.binary_erosion(data, kernel, border_value=1).astype(np.uint8)
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my real case, it is also reducing the white pixels in all directions. I wan to strictly apply towards south direction only. Is not it possible?